# Добавить хеш git в исходный код

Tags: c++, git, visual-c++

Как заставить Visual Studio автоматом при сборке присваивать макросу GIT_HASH значение хеша git, без использования дополнительных утилит/установки поддержки дополнительных языков. Чтобы на чистой машине, с установленным Visual Studio и git можно было собрать такой код:

```
std::cout << "git hash: " << GIT_HASH << std::endl;
```

Comment: Хеш чего? Последнего коммита? Коммита на какой ветке?

Comment: Взгляните на [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3443485/5767249).

Comment: @maestro ага, что-то вроде `git rev-parse --short=12 HEAD`

Comment: @maestro как гитом получить хеш понятно, не понятно как его в коде, в виде константы получить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте Pre-Build Event, в нем выполняйте echo и git rev-parse:

```
echo | set /p _=#define GIT_HASH > rev.h
git rev-parse --short=12 HEAD >> rev.h
```

В свойствах проекта можно задать сразу несколько команд отдельными строчками.
Конструкция `echo | set /p _=` позволяет убрать перевод строки.

Пример использования rev.h :

```
#include "rev.h"
#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)
#define GIT_HASH_STR STRINGIFY(GIT_HASH)

int main() {
    std::cout << GIT_HASH_STR << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный вариант с использованием `for /f` (так же в Pre-Build Event - Command Line)

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"git rev-parse --short=12 HEAD"') do @echo #define GIT_HASH "%%a" > git_hash.h
```

Перед сборкой будет создаваться файл `git_hash.h` содержащий строку:

```
#define GIT_HASH "325f66c2c290"
```

Использование:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "git_hash.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << GIT_HASH << std::endl;
}
```